# What arguments make this comparison true?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, intel

Apparently there's a vulnerability here? Maybe not, or it's just straightforward?

```
 arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch

 push    ebp
 mov     ebp, esp
 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
 mov     ecx, [eax+0Ch]
 movsx   edx, byte ptr [ecx+2]
 cmp     edx, 4Dh
```

Assuming I control the arguments to this function, what values make that comparison true? What boggles my mind is:

```
mov eax [ebp+arg_4]
mov ecx, [eax+0Ch]
```

If I control arg_4 (which I think is an argument?) then I can make eax whatever I want.
But....eax is used as an ADDRESS in the next line!! How on earth could I be expected to anticipate the address (and thereby control what goes into ecx)?? The addresses are going to be different each time you run this....

Am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: You just need to point it at some location in memory such that the loaded values will make the comparison true. Yes, you will need to know the memory layout for that. You may be able to leak that information or possibly use a fixed offset from the original value. Also, making the program crash may count as a vulnerability already (DOS).

Comment: What do you mean, 'used a fixed offset'? And no, making the program crash doesn't count. I need to make the comparison true, which is harder (for this case).

Comment: If you know an appropriate value is some fixed distance from the original value, you can just adjust eax accordingly. That way you don't need to know the absolute addresses.

Answer (score 2):

In C:

```
char *a[] = { 0, 0, 0, "xxM" };
f(0, a);
```